# Check my work for this calculus word problem.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> The region bounded by the $x$-axis and the graph of $y=\sin x$ is divided by the vertical line $x = k$. If the area of the region $0 \leq x \leq k$ is three times the area of the region $k\leq x\leq \pi, \; k =$?

Does this mean:

$$\int_0^k \sin x\, \mathrm{d}x = 3\int_k^{\pi} \sin x\, \mathrm{d}x $$

$$ -\cos x\vert_0^k = 3\left( -\cos x \vert^{\pi}_k \right) $$

$$ \left(1-\cos k\right) = 3\left(1-\cos k\right) $$ which is valid only if $\cos k = 0$ which only happens when $k=0$

Comment: Almost. $-\cos x|_k^\pi=-\cos\pi+\cos k=1+\cos k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming there's a typo in statement of the problem if your bounds are to be correct (and if the problem is to make sense!): "the area of the region $x \leq x \leq k$: I assume you meant the inequalities $0 \leq x \leq k$.

Aside from that:

$$-\cos\Big|_k^\pi = -\cos \pi + \cos k = 1 + \cos k$$

Comment: Your problem set-up was perfect. But if you think about your end result, it really doesn't make sense: $0 + 3\cdot 0 \neq$ area between x-axis and $\sin x$ bounded by $0\leq x \leq \pi =$ area $ = 2$

Comment: That is why I asked here, when I know that I am making a mistake and something is just not right, I tend to lock up and get tunnel vision, that is why I post so many problems here, for the other set (of many) eyes.